# How to Enable Spotify Music Playback in Flutter WebView on iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, webview

I'm developing a Flutter application that includes a WebView to display an artist's playlist from Spotify.

On Android, everything works as expected: tapping on a song plays a sample of it directly within the WebView.

However, on iOS, the same action redirects the user to a page suggesting they download the Spotify app, without playing any song sample.

Is this an issue with my code is it a result of Apple's security policies affecting WebView content playback?

I'm using an old version of https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter (2.4.0), however I also have tried with the 4.5.0 version.

Here's my code:

```
class _MusicPageState extends State<MusicPage> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
  Completer<WebViewController>();

  ValueNotifier<bool> isLoading = ValueNotifier(false);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      _controller.future.then((value) {
        value.reload();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Material(
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () {
            _controller.future.then((value) {
              value.goBack();
            });
            return Future.value(false);
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Música',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6?.copyWith(
                      color: CustomColors.whiteColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const UserWidget(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            body: Stack(
              children: [
                WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'https://open.spotify.com/intl-pt/artist/487N2T9nIPEHrlTZLL3SQs',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                    _controller.complete(webViewController);
                  },
                  // ignore: prefer_collection_literals
                  javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
                    _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
                  ].toSet(),
                  onPageStarted: (String url) {
                    print('Page started loading: $url');
                  },
                  onPageFinished: (String url) {
                    print('Page finished loading: $url');
                  },
                  gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                  onProgress: (v) {
                    if (v < 100) {
                      isLoading.value = true;
                    } else {
                      isLoading.value = false;
                    }
                  },
                ),
                ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                  valueListenable: isLoading,
                  builder: (context, value, _) {
                    return Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Visibility(
                        visible: value,
                        child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                  valueListenable: isLoading,
                  builder: (context, value, _) {
                    return Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            color: CustomColors.secondaryColor,
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                          child: Visibility(
                            visible: !value,
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                _controller.future.then((value) {
                                  value.reload();
                                });
                              },
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.refresh,
                                color: CustomColors.whiteColor,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  JavascriptChannel _toasterJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context) {
    return JavascriptChannel(
        name: 'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
          );
        });
  }
```